# Why will DateTime not create an object from date read from file?

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to create a `DateTime` object from a date string read form a file. The file is a CSV on the server. I get one line at a time from it using `fgets()` and split it up.

I keep getting "Trailing data" and "Unexpected data" errors whenever using the string directly, but if I echo the string and paste it in place of the `$time` variable, it works fine. I figure I need to clean the string, but all functions I've tried still don't work.

The date looks like: `"2015-11-24 8:52:46 AM"` in the file and when echoed.

```
$splitLine = explode(",", $line);      
$time = $splitLine[1];
$timezone = "America/Halifax";
$convertedTime = DateTime::createFromFormat(
  "Y-m-d h:i:s A",
  $time,
  new DateTimeZone($timezone)
);
```

Comment: First, why are you using fgets() and explode() rather than fgetcsv()?

Comment: Second, what does this value actually look like in the file? Do a `var_dump($time)`

Comment: Well, that helped figure it out. Thanks @MarkBaker. The string had " in it as well.